# Rebuilding lists from a single list of objects, based on the value of attributes

Tags: java, list

I am iterating through a `list` of certain `objects` (each object has two attributes `message` (string type) and `messageFrom`(long type). I want to transfer `message` attribute to some specific list depending on the `messageFrom`. Thus, all the `message` having same `messageFrom` must go in same list. So, at the end, I should have no. of lists corresponding to all `messageFrom`.

What is the best (performance optimised) way to implement this ?

Comment: Have you written a non-optimized version of this? Has it proven itself to be a bottleneck in your application? Otherwise, you're probably just wasting your time on premature optimization? Or, are you having trouble implementing this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `HashMap`.

```
Map<Long, ArrayList<String>> data = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<String>>();
// where T is the type of your object
for (T t : list) {
    if (!data.containsKey(t.messageFrom)) {
        data.put(t.messageFrom, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    data.get(t.messageFrom).add(t.message);
}
```

Now you have a Map that maps each `messageFrom` to it's list of messages.

***EDIT***

Here is a complete working example:

```
public class ListSplitter {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // let's build up the original list
        List<MyObject> oList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            oList.add(new MyObject((long) i, "Hello"));
            oList.add(new MyObject((long) i, "World"));
        }

        // now oList contains 20 items:
        // 2 messages ("Hello" and "World") for each messageFrom field

        // now let's split them up
        Map<Long, ArrayList<String>> data = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<String>>();
        for (MyObject m : oList) {
            if (!data.containsKey(m.messageFrom)) {
                data.put(m.messageFrom, new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            data.get(m.messageFrom).add(m.message);
        }

        // now you have a map that looks like this:
        //
        // [0] -> "Hello" : "World"
        // [1] -> "Hello" : "World"
        // ...

        // you can now print out the values as such:
        for (Entry<Long, ArrayList<String>> tuple : data.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Messages from " + tuple.getKey());
            for (String msg : tuple.getValue()) {
                System.out.println(" -> " + msg);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {
        public long messageFrom;
        public String message;

        public MyObject(long from, String msg) {
            messageFrom = from;
            message = msg;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(MyObject m) {
            if (messageFrom == m.messageFrom) {
            return message.compareTo(m.message);
            } else {
                return messageFrom - m.messageFrom;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof MyObject)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return messageFrom == m.messageFrom
                    && message.equals(m.message);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return messageFrom;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we have a complete working example so that it can be handy for further references.im unable to figure out the main method for this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a map of lists:

```
Map<Long,List<String>> map = new HashMap<Long,List<String>>();
for (MyObject obj: myList) {
    List<String> list = map.get(obj.messageFrom);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(obj.messageFrom, list);
    }
    list.add(obj.message);
}
```

Comment: can we have a complete working example so that it can be handy for further references.im unable to figure out the main method for this snippet.

Comment: Could you please help on this !!!Unable to figure out how this will work.can you simulate it with a java program